# Python subprocess multiple non blocking communicates

Tags: python, subprocess, ros

I start a script with:

```
t = subprocess.Popen('rosrun ros_pkg ros_node', shell=True, 
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

I then want to communictate with that process like this:

```
stdout = t.communicate('new command')[0]
print(stdout)
if stdout == []:
   logic
stdout = t.communicate('new command')[0]
....
```

The problem is that after t.commincate the subprocess closes

There are solutions for similar problems but nothing worked for me yet please help

Comment: Maybe a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now switched from using subprocess to using pexpect.
My syntax is now as follows:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('rosrun ros_pkg ros_node')
command = child.sendline('new command')
output = child.read_nonblocking(10000, timeout=1)
....
logic
....
command = child.sendline('new command')
output = child.read_nonblocking(10000, timeout=1)
```

Many thanks to novel_yet_trivial on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2o2viz/subprocess_popen_multiple_times/

Answer (score 0):

Using `t.communicate()` will close the input pipe after sending the data, meaning it can only be called once in order to send something to the subprocess.

However you can use `t.stdin.write()` to do sequential writes without closing the pipe and then use `t.stdin.readline()` to get the output. These work the same way the handler returned by `open()` does.

```
import subprocess


t = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)

#These calls will have their results written to the output pipe
t.stdin.write('hi there ')
t.stdin.write('hi again\n')
#However the input data is buffered first, so call flush() before reading
t.stdin.flush()

#Read from the pipe
a = t.stdout.readline()
print(a)

t.stdin.write('hi back at you\n')
t.stdin.flush()


a = t.stdout.readline()
print(a)
```